# How to concatenate a variable between strings in an LPSTR?

Tags: c++, winapi

I do have this function defined in windows playsoundapi.h.

```
PlaySound(L"D:\\resources\\English\\A.wav", NULL, SND_LOOP);
```

I want to concatenate a variable to replace "A.wav" in c++.
The variable is of type `char*`
Can anyone suggest a solution to this please? Much appreciated.

Comment: Representing a filename using anything but Unicode is a bug waiting to happen. Does your variable of type `char*` contain UTF-8?

Answer (score 3):

In C++17 or above use `std::filesystem::path` which is more handy for such scenario:

```cpp
using std::filesystem::path;

path file = ...; // L"A.wav" // here can be wide characters things and regular character things - proper conversion is done implicitly
path base{L"D:\\resources\\English"};
PlaySound((base / file).c_str(), NULL, SND_LOOP);
```

Note that [std::filesystem::path::c_str()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/native) returns `const wchar_t*` on Windows and `const char *` on other platforms.

> #### Return value
>
> The native string representation of the pathname, using native syntax, native character type, and native character encoding. This string is suitable for use with OS APIs.

Comment: Since `path::c_str()` returns a `wchar_t*`, you should call `PlaySoundW()` directly, instead of relying on `PlaySound()` mapping to `PlaySoundW()`

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough

```
std::wstring var = ...;
PlaySound((L"D:\\resources\\English\\" + var).c_str(), NULL, SND_LOOP);
```

But if your variable is something other than a `std::wstring`, then that is a different question. Please add more details if that is the case.

***EDIT***

It seems the variable is type `char*`. One possible solution is to make a `std::wstring` variable from the `char*` variable

```
char* var = ...;
std::wstring tmp(var, var + strlen(var));
PlaySound((L"D:\\resources\\English\\" + tmp).c_str(), NULL, SND_LOOP);
```

This does assume that there are no encoding issues in copying from `char` to `wchar_t` but again that's a detail not provided in the question.

Also you should consider why the variable is `char*` in the first place. You are working with an API that requires wide characters, so why not use wide characters in your code?

Comment: Don't you also need a `.c_str()` ?

Comment: @paolo No, that would actually be an error. Because then you would be using `+` on two pointers, which isn't allowed.

Comment: @john you missed the point what Paolo wrote.

Comment: Yes, I messed up. Corrected now. Apologies to @paolo

Comment: `std::wstring tmp(var, var + strlen(var));` is not the correct way to convert a `char*` string to a `wstring`. This will work only for ASCII characters, but not for non-ASCII characters. You need a *data conversion* instead, such as via `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's why I said *This does assume that there are no encoding issues*. I doubt the OP knows anything about character encoding so I didn't go any further with that topic.

Answer (score -1):

Assign your `char*` string to a `std::string`, which you can then concatenate with your base path, and then use the `std::string::c_str()` method to get a `const char*` pointer  that you can pass to `PlaySound()`, eg:

```
std::string fileName = "A.wav";
PlaySoundA(("D:\\resources\\English\\" + fileName).c_str(), NULL, SND_LOOP);
```